# Call to undefined method Imdhemy\AppStore\ClientFactory::mock() in Laravel

Tags: php, ios, laravel, in-app-subscription

I am trying to integrate ios in-app purchase Subscription in laravel when I tried mock testing to check the response data I am getting this error. Is there any one who tried IOS in-app purchase in laravel?

I am trying to integrate ios in-app purchase Subscription in laravel when I tried mock testing to check the response data I am getting this error. Is there any one who tried IOS in-app purchase in laravel?

```
Call to undefined method Imdhemy\AppStore\ClientFactory::mock()
```

Here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Imdhemy\AppStore\ClientFactory;
use Imdhemy\AppStore\Exceptions\InvalidReceiptException;
use Imdhemy\Purchases\Facades\Product;
use JsonException;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Libraries\MP3File;
use Imdhemy\Purchases\Facades\Subscription;

use Auth;
use DB;
use Mail;
use View;
use Session;
use Storage;

class TestApiController extends Controller
{   
   
    public function ValidateReceipt(): void
    {
        // Create the expected body
        $responseBody = [
            'environment' => 'Sandbox',
            'status' => 0,
            'latest_receipt_info' => [
                [
                    'product_id' => 'fake_product_id',
                    'quantity' => '1',
                    'transaction_id' => 'fake_transaction_id',
                    // other fields omitted
                ],
            ],
            // other fields omitted
        ];

        // Create the response instance. It requires to JSON encode the body.
        $responseMock = new Response(200, [], json_encode($responseBody, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));

        // Use the client factory to mock the response.
        $client = ClientFactory::mock($responseMock);

        // --------------------------------------------------------------
        // The created client could be injected into a service
        // --------------------------------------------------------------
        // The part is up to you as a developer.
        //
        // Inside that service you can use the client as follows
        $verifyResponse = Product::appStore($client)->receiptData('fake_receipt_data')->verifyReceipt();
        // The returned response will contain the data from the response body you provided in the first line.

    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you check if you have the correct package? When you try to visit the file by clicking (Alt + left click or Ctr + left click in Visual code), does it open up?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking that you're not using a old version of that package, or `imdhemy/laravel-purchases` if you're using that.

I had a similar issue just now. Turns out I was using a very old version of `imdhemy/laravel-purchases` and needed to update it!

You can see that the `mock` function does exist in newer versions of `ClientFactory` - https://github.com/imdhemy/appstore-iap/blob/release/1.x/src/ClientFactory.php#L55